# Function tried to send a message of type number - Error

Tags: node-red

I am getting "Function tried to send a message of type number" error when I deploy my flow. I am quite new the node-red.

```
flow.set('previous_motor_speed',motor_speed);
return [motor_speed, current];
}

//Return nothing if not required
else { flow.set('previous_motor_speed',motor_speed);}
return null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not return a raw value, you have to return a `msg` object. As a rule any value should be stored in `msg.payload`

So at worst is should be:

```
return [{payload: motor_speed}, {payload: current}]
```

(as a rule you should not be creating new `msg` objects on the fly like this, but without seeing more of your function code I can't say more).